# Implement Paste Link for this code

Tags: vba, excel

I have this code which allows to a copy a customized range from any sheet and paste it to a fixed range on sheet 2. This code works but I need to implement paste link function in this code, so that if i want to make any changes to the data in DB it will auto update in sheet 2 as well.  Here is the code I have done so far. Thank you in advance

```
Sub CustomizedInputFixedoutput()


Dim rng As Range, _
 inp As Range, _
 ws As Worksheet


Set inp = Selection
On Error Resume Next
Set rng = Application.InputBox("Copy to", Type:=8)
On Error GoTo 0
If TypeName(rng) <> "Range" Then
    MsgBox "Cancelled", vbInformation
    Exit Sub
Else
    rng.Parent.Activate
    rng.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet 2").Range("B2:N5").Value = rng.Value
End If
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

I felt sure this had to be a duplicate but searching [excel-vba] Paste Link found a few questions without any accepted answers and none that matched to OP desire to paste into a specific range.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CustomizedInputFixedoutput()
Dim CopyRng As Range
Dim PasteRng As Range
Dim Msg As String
Dim Response As VbMsgBoxResult


    Set CopyRng = Selection
    On Error Resume Next
    Set PasteRng = Application.InputBox("Select a cell to copy to", Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not PasteRng Is Nothing Then 'user clicked Cancel
        If PasteRng.Count > 1 Then
            'Get confirmation to paste to multi-cell range
            Msg = "Are you sure you want to paste to " & PasteRng.Address & "?" _
            & vbCrLf & vbCrLf _
            & "Results may be unexpected if you proceed."
            Response = MsgBox(Msg, vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Confirm multi-cell paste range")
        End If
        If Response = vbYes Or PasteRng.Count = 1 Then
            CopyRng.Copy
            PasteRng.Parent.Activate
            PasteRng.Activate
            ActiveSheet.Paste Link:=True
        Else
            MsgBox "Cancelled", vbInformation
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "Cancelled", vbInformation
    End If
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: So i cant paste into a specific range?

Comment: You could but if you select a paste range that is more than one cell and it isn't exactly the same size as your selection then your whole selection may not be copied or you may have cells displaying 0s below.

Comment: ^^ that. note that the behavior is identical to when you paste manually.

Comment: yes but the issue is the data i want to paste is only column B and Column D in that case i have to hardcode the range.

Comment: Select the cells you want to copy and run the code selecting a single cell on Sheet2 to paste into.  Then do it selecting multiple cells on Sheet2 to see what happens.

Comment: The user wants the data to be copied and pasted with one click:/ . That is the reason i resorted to this hardcode. Previously i did something similar to what you did too

Answer (score 1):

Here you copy the range:

> ```
> rng.Copy
> ```

And here you are assigning the value of B2:N5 the same value as `rng`.

> ```
> Sheets("Sheet 2").Range("B2:N5").Value = rng.Value
> ```

The problem is that that code isn't *pasting* anything from the clipboard! You don't need to `.Copy` anything to assign cell values like this.

Use the [`Worksheet.Paste`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821951.aspx) method instead of assigning the values (then the `.Copy` will serve its purpose), and set the optional parameter `Links` to `True`, like this:

```
Worksheets("Sheet 2").Range("B2:N5").Select
Worksheets("Sheet 2").Paste Links:=True
```

Comment: I don't think you can use both Destination: and Link: parameters in the Worksheet.Paste method.

Comment: Getting a select range of method class failed on the range.select line:/

Comment: @Niva I don't have VBA handy at the moment. the idea is that you select/activate the range you want to paste onto, and use `Worksheet.Paste Links:=True` to perform the paste.

Comment: still not able to diagnose this issue. hais;/ So near yet so far!